# How to identify whether the input is an integer or something else on easy68k?

Tags: assembly, easy68k

I am just trying to check if the input that the user enters is an integer or something else. I know that I probably need to take the input as a string and then check every part of the string. But I am still lost with how to implement it.

Comment: With any programming problem (but especially with assembler), you need to break it down into manageable steps.  For example, let's say you had the user enter just 1 character.  How would you check to see if it was a number?  Well, what does it mean to be a number?  Is 'Q' a number?  How about '7'?  With that in mind, how would you check to see if what they entered was a number?  While you could check each of the possible values for a number (0-9), it turns out that all digits are right next to each other in the list of characters.  So you can check to see if each character < '0' or > '9'.

Comment: If the user enters a string like 123, that is still a string (series or sequence of bytes or characters) until you do something with that: that something is a like parsing, albeit simple parsing. Parsing can fail so you need a success case and a fail case, if you encounter something not recognized as an integer.